# find same value from two column sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to find id follow and follow back user from one table...

here i want to get only that data who is follow back like here

1 is follow 5 and 5 also follow back to 1 so when i fire query that time only see cid=1 and u_id=5

```html
<pre class="lang-sql prettyprint prettyprinted"><code><span class="kwd">cid</span><span class="pln">              </span><span class="kwd">u_id</span><span class="pln"> 
</span><span class="com">---------            ---------</span><span class="pln">
</span><span class="lit">1</span><span class="pln">                5
</span><span class="lit">2</span><span class="pln">                23
</span><span class="lit">3</span><span class="pln">                </span><span class="lit">45</span><span class="pln">
</span><span class="lit">4</span><span class="pln">                </span><span class="lit">87</span><span class="pln">
</span><span class="lit">5</span><span class="pln">                1</span></code></pre>
```

here is query

```
SELECT * FROM `recent_activities` WHERE cid=1
```

i want to find it from only cid..please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, (used a Self Join here to solve the issue).

```
SELECT  T1.cid,T1.u_id 
FROM    TABLE1 AS T1
    INNER JOIN TABLE1 AS T2 ON T1.cid = T2.u_id AND T1.u_id = T2.cid
```